# Is electric potential and electrical potential energy refering to the same thing?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is electric potential and electrical potential energy refering to the same thing? I think i might have them mixed up

Answer (score 3):

No. The electric potential energy $U_q$ of a charge $q$ is the electric potential $\phi$ at that point in space, *multiplied by the charge*:

$$U_q=q\phi.$$

You can think of electric potential as electric potential energy *per unit of charge*. And think of electric potential as something that exists at every point, regardless of whether there is a charge there to have electric potential energy or not.

Another way to remember this is by analogy: electric *potential energy* is to electric *potential* as electric *force* is to electric *field*.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Really cleared things up!

Comment: Glad to be of help.